# Matching two lists in excel

Tags: list, excel, excel-formula, matching, vba

I am trying to compare two months sales to each other in excel in the most automated way possible (just so it will be quicker for future months)

[image]

This months values are all worked out through formulae and last months will be copy and pasted into D:E. However as you can see there are some customers that made purchases last month and then did not this month (and vice versa). I basically need to be have all CustomerID's matching row by row. So for example it to end up like this:

[image]

Can anyone think of a good way of doing this without having to do it all manually? Thanks

Comment: I would recommend that you invest some time in learning about Excel macros.  Yes, there is an overhead, but it really is the tool to use for your problem.  And it's a skill which you will reuse later on in your career.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SUMIFS function or VLOOKUP.  Like this:

http://screencast.com/t/VTBZrfHjo8tk

You should just have your entire customer list on one sheet and then add up the values associated with them month over month.  The design you are describing is going to be a nightmare to maintain over time and serves no purpose.  I can understand you would like to see the customers in a row like that, which is why I suggest SUMIFS.

Answer (score 0):

This option compare only two columns, I think you do to think anoter way,
first I will add the date/month and then you can add down the next month value:
[image]

then you can use a simply pivot to see more month in the some time

[image]

any case if you want to format your two columns, you can use this code (you will to update with you reference, I used the date from your img example)

```
Sub OrderMachColumns()
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim sortarray(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As String
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim TempTxt10 As String
Dim TempTxt11 As String
Dim TempTxt20 As String
Dim TempTxt22 As String
lastRow = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row ' I use column A, same your example

For x = 3 To lastRow * 2
Cells(x, 1).Select
    If Cells(x, 1) = "" Then GoTo B
    If Cells(x, 4) = "" Then GoTo A
    If Cells(x, 1) = Cells(x, 4) Then
    Else
        If Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(x - 1, 4).Value Then
            Range(Cells(x - 1, 4), Cells(x - 1, 5)).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ElseIf Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(x + 1, 4).Value Then
            Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 2)).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Else
            sortarray(1, 1) = Cells(x, 1).Value
            sortarray(1, 2) = "Cells(" & x & ", 1)"
            sortarray(2, 1) = Cells(x, 4).Value
            sortarray(2, 2) = "Cells(" & x & ", 4)"
            For Z = LBound(sortarray) To UBound(sortarray)
              For y = Z To UBound(sortarray)
                If UCase(sortarray(y, 1)) > UCase(sortarray(Z, 1)) Then
                  TempTxt11 = sortarray(Z, 1)
                  TempTxt12 = sortarray(Z, 2)
                  TempTxt21 = sortarray(y, 1)
                  TempTxt22 = sortarray(y, 2)
                  sortarray(Z, 1) = TempTxt21
                  sortarray(y, 1) = TempTxt11
                  sortarray(Z, 2) = TempTxt22
                  sortarray(y, 2) = TempTxt12
                End If
               Next y
            Next Z

            Select Case sortarray(1, 2)
                Case "Cells(" & x & ", 1)"
                    Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 2)).Select
                Case "Cells(" & x & ", 4)"
                    Range(Cells(x, 4), Cells(x, 5)).Select

            End Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
    End If
A:
Next x
B:
End Sub
```